# C++ program doesn't completely read huge input. Why?

Tags: c++, xcode, input, copy-paste

I want to solve a programming contest task (C++ with XCode) which has a relatively big input (300 lines). When copying a test input into the console, it doesn't read it all.
So I have written a minimalistic test program to simply read in 300 lines:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    string xxx;
    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        cin >> xxx;
    return 0;
}
```

If I execute it and copy 340 lines with "aaaaaaaaaa" into the console, it doesn't end. If I stop it with the debugger, it says i = 92. If I then continue, it quits.
But when I copy pieces of 50 lines into the console, it quits immeadiately as it should...

Can anyone help me with this?

PS: I inserted the 'ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);', because I read that this would spped the input up.

Comment: cin >> xxx will read a word, not lines. You need to use getline.

Comment: Make your `string xxx`a global variable instead of a local, and check again. Possibly you are killing your local (function) stack.

Comment: (OT: I would hesitate to call 300 lines "relatively big input". I frequently run tests on files exceeding 10,000 lines of text; finding storage space is generally not a problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem with X-Code but it works with Qt. So I use Qt now.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to solve a programming contest task (C++ with XCode) which has a relatively big input (300 lines). When copying a test input into the console, it doesn't read it all

This is possible when you have more than one word per line because `cin >> xx` will read words as opposed to lines.

You would need to use the [getline method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to actually read lines.

```
while (getline(cin, xxx));
```

> If I execute it and copy 340 lines with "aaaaaaaaaa" into the console, it doesn't end. If I stop it with the debugger, it says i = 92.

Yes, this is exactly the same symptom. Even if you had one word per line, you would reach only 300 lines, never 340.

Here is the whole code I would write for your reference:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    string xxx;
    while (getline(cin, xxx))
        cout << xxx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What sort of limit is the OP encountering?

Comment: So is that a built-in limit to `cin`? (Addendum: see the OP's attempt to debug, using 340 "words"/"lines".)

Comment: @Jongware: The OP reads 300 words, so 340 words will not be read in.

Comment: But then where does `i=92` and his never-ending loop come into play? (I'll accept "In some code not shown in this post" as a good answer ;-)

Comment: @Jongware: beats me based on the code shown, but the intent of reading line with operator>> was wrong either way.

Comment: For this test, I have only one word per line.
I also didn't want to read in all the 340 lines but just wanted the programm to read in its 300 lines, ignore the other ones and then end. But it doesn't end.
I tested your programm end with 314 input lines, it only echoed 93 and then stuck.

Comment: I didn't not look close at the code, but may it not possibly also be a buffer problem of the console itself not being able to hold all pasted data?

Comment: @RaFi: I really cannot reproduce your issue, nor my friends that I asked to try.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> string` inputs words, not lines. Try:

```
string xxx;

while (getline(cin, xxx)) {
  ;
}
```

to input a full line at a time into `xxx`.